# Do adjacency effects "wrap-around" planet surfaces?

Tags: stellaris

If I land a colony on the very "edge" of the planet surface map (say, the far left), will the adjacency bonus "wrap around" to provide the bonus (to the tile on the far right)?

Comment: I can't say for certain, but I tend towards no. Will check in the evening.

Comment: Attention citizens of the future. This question references a _very_ old version of Stellaris and does not relate to the current state of the game.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm getting all nostalgic for Tiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Doesn't look like it. Hand-drawn circles for your pleasure.

[image]

Comment: Finally, proof that the world is flat!

Comment: I would not expect North Pole to border South Pole, but I would expect tiles on each side of the antimeridian to border each other. (I'm of course assuming that planet surface is shows the same way as conventional Earth maps, which may not be true.)